# Delphi: Show the same Graph on 2 different forms

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, pascal, teechart

I would like to show the same graph (TChart) on 2 different forms. on the first there is a small version, but i would like the user to be able to click a button to show a bigger version of the graph.

Comment: Where's the problem, what doesn't work?

Comment: Do you need both graphs to be visible at the same time?

Comment: Yes both graphs should still be visible. The ways i have tried haven't worked, including setting the series equal to each other - 'read only' error doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have two different controls in which you supply the same set of data.
or you can try setting the parent of the control on the new form.

```
TSmallForm = class
...
procedure TSmallForm.Button1Click(sender : TObject)
var
  F : TForm;
begin
  F := TForm.Create;
  try
    ChartComponent.Parent := F;
    ChartComponent.Align := alClient;
    F.ShowModal;
  finally
    F.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Maybe resetting the parent of the chart after the show modal (within the finally) would be a good idea.

Comment: @Ralph Well, not within the finally for the `Free`. It would need a new try/finally block.

Comment: I did not write complete code just wanted to show how to move a control.

Comment: Thank you, will have a play with that.